# How to stream a text file from Onedrive URL in C#?

Tags: c#, text-files, onedrive

I have my code working when a file is saved localy with the code below, please see:

```
string strExeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string strWorkPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strExeFilePath) + "/creds.txt";
string[] lines = await System.IO.File.ReadAllLinesAsync(strWorkPath);
```

but, what I want to do right now is, I am trying to host the file on Onedrive so that I can access the text file everywhere. I give my file a public access and already have the url:

But when I tried to request the file with an HTTP request:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string result = client.GetStringAsync("https://1drv.ms/t/some_public_file_url").Result;
```

This is the response:

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0PO1.png]

**PS: This is what the file look like in onedrive:**
[image]

When I access the url, it looks like this in the browser:
[image]

Has anyone with a better idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: What happens if you enter that url in the web browser?

Comment: I added a screenshot, please see:

Comment: Try to access the file direct from url, not to send request to the url.

Comment: @H.Sarxha how ?

Answer (score 1):

I found it! the raw data can be found in the network tab of the developer tools. you just need to get copy the URL that returns the raw data and it's good to go:

Please see:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this helped me quite a bit. in my case I have a json file. To be specific, in my case, in the Network tab, I chose the one that began with "thumbnail". Under "Headers", there is a `:path:` value. From there I extracted the `docid` parameter, then URL decoded it. I then pasted that value into a browser and got a JSON doc. In the JSON there is a `@content.downloadUrl` parameter, which gave the URL that directly downloads the text file. That URL I was able to use in my code. Don't forget to set the file to be downloadable from OneDrive without authentication.